# Discord.js | Chat transcript (txt) gets saved

Tags: javascript, discord.js, fs

I ran into a problem with a discord.js ticket transcript command. When I use the transcript command, a .txt file gets created and sent into the channel, this works just fine. The issue is that the file gets saved locally, which isn't what I want.

The code for creating the txt + sending:

```
fs.writeFileSync(`${message.channel.name}.txt`, content.join('\n'), err => { if (err) throw err });

doneEmbed(message, lang.ticket.transcript.replace('{name}', `${message.channel.name}.txt`));
return message.channel.send(new MessageAttachment(`${message.channel.name}.txt`, `${message.channel.name}.txt`));
```

`doneEmbed` is just a pre-created embed to make the code cleaner, in case you're confused:

```
//Emoji file
const e = require('../../data/config/emojis.json');

//Embed
module.exports.doneEmbed = function doneEmbed(message, desc) {
    let embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setDescription(e.done + desc)
        .setColor(c.done)
    message.channel.send(embed);
}
```

File structure, where the transcript gets saved ( | exstare.txt &  | test.txt):

[image: FileStructure]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application need to save the file before sending it as attachment. Thats why its required to save the file.

But there is an simple sollution for this problem. If you dont want the file stored forever in your project folder, just delete the file **after** you've sent the file as attachment with your Discord bot. Take a look on this website for some examples how to delete a file with *FileSystem*: https://www.tutorialkart.com/nodejs/delete-a-file-in-nodejs-using-node-fs